# Ios objective c best method for secure delete

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

We have files in SQLite wrapped with bcrypt for SQLite encryption. We pull sensitive files out of the db for the end user to view. We need a best practice for deleting a file and having unrecoverable. We have to give some assurances around deletion.

Looking for links, ideas and pitfalls around assuring deletion.

Comment: Due to the way flash works, you CANNOT securely delete a file after you write to it. However, since your db is already encrypted you should be fine. Just don't write the decrypted file to file.